# JtaTransactionManager no rollback after failed commit during "flush"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta, spring-transactions

**Update:** I was testing it with Bitronix TM and it rollbacks perfectly, so the issue is in JBoss TM (arjuna) or in my configuration.

**Update 2:** It looks like transactions are not global, I've tried different datasources, Bitronix datasource has *allowLocalTransactions* property and after setting it my application throws an exception that something tried to use it in local mode. If I use Bitronix with this datasource it works without any errors. I believe there is something wrong in configs.

I have an issue with JTA transactions. I'm using Tomcat 7 + Hibernate 4 + Spring 3 + JBoss TS 4 and JTA transactions.

Suppose there is the following method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void testMethod() {
    insertOfSomeNewEntityInstance();
    updateOfAnotherEntity();
}

private void insertOfSomeNewEntityInstance() {
    SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
    someEntityDAO.save(entity);
}

private void updateOfAnotherEntity() {
    AnotherEntity anotherEntity = anotherEntityDAO.findBySomeProperty(1L);
    anotherEntity.incrementSomeValue();
    anotherEntityDAO.save(anotherEntity);
}
```

If this method throws *"org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)"* during "updateOfAnotherEntity()" method execution or any other runtime exception that might happen during "flush" (Hibernate also shows: *HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)*.
then the result of insertOfSomeNewEntityInstance() execution is not rolled back.

After debugging this issue I found "doCommit" method in org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransaction Manager

```
@Override
    protected void doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) {
        JtaTransactionObject txObject = (JtaTransactionObject) status.getTransaction();
        try {
            int jtaStatus = txObject.getUserTransaction().getStatus();
            if (jtaStatus == Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION) {
                throw new UnexpectedRollbackException("JTA transaction already completed - probably rolled back");
            }
            if (jtaStatus == Status.STATUS_ROLLEDBACK) {
                try {
                    txObject.getUserTransaction().rollback();
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug("Rollback failure with transaction already marked as rolled back: " + ex);
                    }
                }
                throw new UnexpectedRollbackException("JTA transaction already rolled back (probably due to a timeout)");
            }
            txObject.getUserTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (RollbackException ex) {
            throw new UnexpectedRollbackException(
                    "JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout)", ex);
        }
        catch (HeuristicMixedException ex) {
            throw new HeuristicCompletionException(HeuristicCompletionException.STATE_MIXED, ex);
        }
        catch (HeuristicRollbackException ex) {
            throw new HeuristicCompletionException(HeuristicCompletionException.STATE_ROLLED_BACK, ex);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            throw new TransactionSystemException("Unexpected internal transaction state", ex);
        }
        catch (SystemException ex) {
            throw new TransactionSystemException("JTA failure on commit", ex);
        }
    }
```

If "txObject.getUserTransaction().commit();" fails with RollbackException then this method throws UnexpectedRollbackException and here is the part of org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPl atformTransactionManager processCommit(...) that catches it:

```
}
 catch (UnexpectedRollbackException ex) {
                // can only be caused by doCommit
                triggerAfterCompletion(status, TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_ROLLED_BACK);
                throw ex;
    }
```

I do not see any rollbacks in triggerAfterCompletion() method and after this method everything else just cleans up resources.

**To sum up**, spring/jboss just commits the result of insertOfSomeNewEntityInstance(), fails to execute updateOfAnotherEntity() because of concurrent modification error, and does not rollback anything. If I manually throw any runtime or checked exception from updateOfAnotherEntity() it rollbacks correctly, the issue occurs only when Hibernate throws some runtime exception during "flush".

**hibernate.cfg**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">${dialect}</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">25</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">TestSessionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</property>
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg">infinispan.xml</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**jbossts-properties.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.commitOnePhase">YES</entry>
    <entry key="CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.defaultTimeout">300</entry>
    <entry key="ObjectStoreEnvironmentBean.transactionSync">ON</entry>
    <entry key="CoreEnvironmentBean.nodeIdentifier">1</entry>
    <entry key="JTAEnvironmentBean.xaRecoveryNodes">1</entry>
    <entry key="JTAEnvironmentBean.xaResourceOrphanFilterClassNames">
        com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.JTATransactionLogXAResourceOrphanFilter
        com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.JTANodeNameXAResourceOrphanFilter
    </entry>

    <entry key="CoreEnvironmentBean.socketProcessIdPort">0</entry>

    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.recoveryModuleClassNames">
        com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.AtomicActionRecoveryModule
        com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule
        com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule
    </entry>

    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.expiryScannerClassNames">
        com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.ExpiredTransactionStatusManagerScanner
    </entry>

    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.recoveryPort">4712</entry>

    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.recoveryAddress"></entry>

    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.transactionStatusManagerPort">0</entry>
    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.transactionStatusManagerAddress"></entry>

    <entry key="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.recoveryListener">YES</entry>

</properties>
```

**Part of applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager" factory-method="transactionManager" id="arjunaTransactionManager"></bean>
    <bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction" factory-method="userTransaction" id="arjunaUserTransaction"></bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="arjunaTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="arjunaUserTransaction"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation"><value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="false" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

**And the log:**

```
Completing transaction for [...testMethod]
Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
BaseTransaction.getStatus
TransactionImple.getStatus
Initiating transaction commit
BaseTransaction.getStatus
TransactionImple.getStatus
BaseTransaction.commit
TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate
SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion
BaseTransaction.getStatus
TransactionImple.getStatus

insert into .....
update ... set ...

BaseTransaction.setRollbackOnly
TransactionImple.setRollbackOnly
BasicAction::preventCommit( BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:3 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING)
HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [...]]
ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:4, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@76d7a0b8 >
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [...]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2509) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3228) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126) [narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1010) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:387) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at $Proxy126.testMethod(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        ...

BasicAction::preventCommit( BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:3 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY)
BasicAction::Abort() for action-id 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:3
SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion
TransactionImple.equals
SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion
BasicAction::removeChildThread () action 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:3 removing TSThread:2
BasicAction::removeChildThread () action 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:3 removing TSThread:2 result = true
TransactionReaper::remove ( BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a800ab:8d15:51b6fe47:3 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED )
Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
Clearing transaction synchronization
Exception
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1013) ~[spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) ~[spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) ~[spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:387) ~[spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at $Proxy126.testMethod(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        ...
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1010) ~[spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [...]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2509) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3228) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165) ~[narayana-jta-4.17.4.Final.jar:4.17.4.Final]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the issue was in the configuration. Tomcat XA pool didn't know about JBoss Transaction Manager. I tried to change driverClassName to TransactionalDriver like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:arjuna:" />
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${database.pool.initialSize}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="${database.pool.maxSize}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.pool.maxSize}"/>
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="DYNAMIC_CLASS=com.example.CustomDatasourceLoader;"/>
```

Unfortunately it was throwing an exception for subtransactions saying that connection belongs to another transaction, so that I had to find another connection pool.

Oracle UCP pool didn't work properly as well, there is no way to change driverClassName to TransactionalDriver because it is hard-coded to OracleDriver.

The following configuration works for me (DBCP XA pool) and correctly rollbacks, commits, supports subtransactions:

```
<bean id="oracleXADataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource">
        <property name="user" value="${database.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="URL" value="${database.url}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dsXAConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.DataSourceXAConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg><ref bean="arjunaTransactionManager"></ref></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><ref bean="oracleXADataSource"></ref></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
        <property name="maxActive" value="${database.pool.maxSize}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="${database.pool.initialSize}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="connFactory" ref="dsXAConnectionFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg name="pool" ref="pool"/>
        <constructor-arg name="stmtPoolFactory"><null></null></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="validationQuery"><null></null></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="defaultReadOnly" value="false"/>
        <constructor-arg name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.ManagedDataSource" depends-on="poolableConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="pool" ref="pool"/>
        <constructor-arg name="transactionRegistry" value="#{dsXAConnectionFactory.getTransactionRegistry()}"/>
    </bean>
```

I have some concerns about using DBCP pool but for now it is the only working solution.